# SOAP Listener using .NET

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, iis-8

I want to make an SOAP listener that work in IIS 8 using SSL protocol that intercept SOAP message and extract XML data from it , to resume :

- The listener must receive SOAP messages
- Extract data
- save it in XML file

(see the attachment picture please) .
[enter link description here](http://i61.tinypic.com/2h4klqv.png)

i still not sure how can i develop it using : Web Service or WCF ...
how can i do a Listener that intercept SOAP message using .net ?

Comment: Did you make any attempt? Did you read the documentation? Did you look for examples / tutorials?

Comment: yes i read many documentation , i want to get the best way to make a Listener that intercept SOAP message